# What field or function i should override to make node have text description in TreeView control when inherit from TreeNode?

Tags: c#, text, treeview, treenode, inheritance

I am trying to inherit from TreeNode to add own nodes to TreeView:

```
class TreeViewItem : TreeNode
{
    public new string Text;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "asd";
    }
}
```

I tried that:

```
    TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem();
    tvi.Text = "asd";
    trv_bd_content.Nodes.Add(tvi);
```

But still getting empty node added to TreeView (node without Text "asd").
What should i do?

Comment: Yes, that won't work.  The TreeView class will still use the original Text property, it doesn't know anything about your new Text field.  You must use the Text property.

Comment: Just remove code inside your class and everything will work. Which behaviour are you going to override (modify) in your new class?

Comment: i have some object with coords and i want to make when it added to TreeView it were showed like that: public string new Text { get: return name + ": " + latitude + " / " + longitude + " / " + H; }

Comment: As I see you want to override Text property which is not virtual. Do `latitude` and 'longitude' change after added to tree or the values are known before you add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you are going to override `TreeNode` just to display some text you build your own.
If values needed for calculation are known before adding the node to tree I would suggest to do it this way:

```
        treeView = new TreeView();
        var node = new TreeNode(
            string.Format("{0}: {1} / {2} / {3}", name, latitude, longitude, H));
        treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
```

Overriding a visual element just to keep additional data in it is not a good idea. Usisally you override visual element to modify it's drawing or something related to it's behavior as visual element.

For keeping corresponding data you could use `Tag` property where you can save any data (untyped). So you can put an instance of a class containing your data.

```
        node.Tag = "AnyData";
```

Comment: This is kinda not what i want. I must have my own **TreeViewItem** added to TreeView, instead of TreeNode. I want easy access to all needed fields inside **TreeViewItem** just by knowing it selected in TreeView. If i store in TreeView TreeNodes, i must search over all instances of another class to find what instance of object math to selected TreeNode in TreeView

Comment: Using Tag is good idea! Thanks, i didn't knew about this thing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the treenode does not use ToString() to get display information. It uses .Text property instead (which doesn't seem to enjoy being overriden )

You could set the Text property in your constructor if you wanted to.

```
class TreeViewItem : TreeNode
{
    // public new string Text;  Remove this so you don't call it

    public TreeViewItem(){
        this.Text = "asd";
    }

    //Treeview doesn't seem to use this
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "asd";
    }
}
```